# Complex loop for re-generating population

Tags: java, for-loop, iterator, genetic-algorithm

I am using a genetic algorithm and I'm trying to re-create individuals in a population (after removing them at the end of the generation). The issue is that the 'crossover' function creates two individuals and the 'mutate' and 'createRandomIndividual' function create one individual. How could I incorporate that in the loop?

```
List<Individual> population = new ArrayList<Individual>();

private void replaceIndividuals(int individualsTurnover) {
    //individualTurnover = number of individuals I need to re-generate
    boolean even = individualsTurnover % 2 == 0;

    for (int i=0; i<individualsTurnover/2; i++){
        replaceIndividuals();
    }

    if (!even)
        mutate();
}

private void replaceIndividuals() {
    int random = generator.nextInt(10);

    if (random < 1) {
        // generates one individual via mutation
        mutate(); 
    }
    else if (random < 2) {
        // generates one individual randomly
        createRandomIndividual();
    }
    else  {
        //generates two individuals by crossing-over individuals from a pool of parents
        crossover();
    }
}
```

Currently too many individuals are being created. The number of individuals creates should be = 'individualTurnover'.

Comment: What exactly are you looking for ?

Comment: Please don't do things like `boolean even = individualsTurnover % 2 == 0 ? true : false`...... `boolean even = individualsTurnover % 2 == 0` is simple enough.

Comment: Nooo I promise you it isnt

Comment: I am doing a proof of concept and I havnt programmed since I left university :-/

Comment: what's the goal is not so clear, maybe showing some more code could help...

Comment: @smk how could I fix my loop so that it creates the right number of individuals. Because the crossover() function creates 2 individuals and the mutate() and creatRandomIndividual() functions create 1 individual.

Comment: @Mark I modified my question. I hope its clear now?

Comment: I don't know much about genetic algorithms, but couldn't you simple call mutate() or createRandomIndividual() twice?

Comment: Where is your population (so where's the data structure that is modified by mutate, createRandomIndividual and crossover)?

Comment: @isnot2bad yes thats what I'm doing temporarily but I prefer not to. I would like to know how to do it this way (described above), I would appreciate it if you could help me with that?

Comment: @isnot2bad it is just a List<Individual> population.

Comment: Cant you just assign probabilities such taht crossover is called 1/4th of times and mutate and other one are callced 1/4th each..

Comment: @smk im not really sure about how to do that..

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood correctly, but generating a new population requires a selection as input. So mutation and crossover will use individuals from that selection and produce new individuals for the new population. That means all you have to do is to loop until the new population is large enough. If it's too large in the end, eliminate exessive individuals.

Comment: @isnot2bad thank you. Interesting point.. I will look into this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might solve your problem. I have changed the method signature slightly

```
 public class Test
    {

        private void replaceIndividuals(int individualsTurnover) {
            //individualTurnover = number of individuals I need to re-generate
           while(individualsTurnover > 1)
           {
               individualsTurnover = individualsTurnover - replaceIndividuals();
               //I am deducting this count because those many individuals are already created
           }
           //This is the only possible count > 0
           if(individualsTurnover == 1)
           {
               mutate();
           }
        }
        /**
         * 
         * @return No of individulas created
         */
        private int  replaceIndividuals() {
            int random = generator.nextInt(10);

            if (random < 1) {
                // generates one individual via mutation
                mutate();
                retrun 1;
            }
            else if (random < 2) {
                // generates one individual randomly
                createRandomIndividual();
                return 1;
            }
            else  {
                //generates two individuals by crossing-over individuals from a pool of parents
                crossover();

                return 2;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Very interesting way of doing it! Thanks. I will try to incorporate this.